# Does libpq support something equivalent of Oracle's array binds?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

Oracle has something they call array binds ([from docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76975/oci05bnd.htm#420697)) where the SQL sent could be `UPDATE mytable SET val = :2 WHERE id = :1` along with an array bind with contents:

```
1 | val1
2 | val2
3 | val3
```

*(PS. The array's size is > 1000 items, the 3 items are for illustration.)*

This is efficient and is done in a single round-trip to the server.

Is this possible using libpq as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL doesn't have anything like that.

I would use a named prepared statement created with `PQprepare` and execute it for each row using `PQexecPrepared`. Similar idea, but a different method.

Comment: ok, too bad. I'm currently using a temporary table, which seems like the fastest method.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to minimize roundtrips, then you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable m
  SET val = t.val
from ( 
  values (:1, :2), (:3, :4), (:5, :6), ....
) as t(id,val)
WHERE t.id = m.id;
```